# Kibana - Create line Chart on Bar Chart in Same graph

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I am a newbie in Elastic Stack and i am trying the following and i am struck.

I want to render a line chart on the bar chart on same graph. I have been browsing for long time now but could not find any link for this.

In Kibana 5.2, is it possible to create a line chart on bar chart on same graph ? Can someone who has done it in the past confirm if it is feasible ?

if yes, can you share any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mix bars and lines it's possible via the Timelion plugin (which is included in Kibana since version 5). Put something like this in the Timelion tab:

```
.es(*).bars(),.es(*).lines()
```

And you should be able to see something like:

[image: Plot]

Now it's just a matter of doing the query you want to plot.

For understanding it in detail, on Timelion tab, on top right corner, you will see a tab - Docs. Once you click on Docs, you will get a link - Go to Tutorial.

Try the link and it walks you through the steps.